# How to put a buffer that clears an array in C?

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that takes a string and assigns it to a char array pointer. I need help putting a buffer clearer so that the array isn't overloaded. I have already wrote the code for the buffer, please assume that it's called clearBuffer() and works fine.

```
// Gets a string from user with min limit and max limit given
void getString(char* str[99], int minlimit, int maxlimit) {
    // local variables
    int handleError = 1, i, len;


    // check if input within min and max limit
    do {

        if (scanf("%99[^\n]%c", str) != 1) // I need help with this part
        {
            clearBuffer();
            continue;
        }
        clearBuffer();
        len= 0;

        // check string length (yes I have to do this manually)
        for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            len++;
        }

        // error for exact char
        if ((len < minlimit|| len > maxlimit) && minlimit == maxlimit) {
            printf("input must be exactly %d chars: ", minlimit);
            len = 0;
        }
        // error for max limit only (if min is 0)
        else if ((len > maxlimit && minlimit == 0)) {
            printf("input must be no more than %d chars: ", maxlimit);
            len = 0;
        }
        // error for min and max limit
        else if ((len < minlimit|| len > maxlimit) && minlimit != maxlimit && minlimit != 0) {
            printf("input must be between %d and %d chars: ", minlimit, maxlimit );
            len = 0;
        }
        else {
            handleError = 0;
        }
    } while (handleError);

}
```

Comment: `char* str[99]` means an array of 99 pointers to `char`, i.e. 99 strings. Is that what you really wanted?

Comment: Since you're asking this question I have to assume that `clearBuffer();` does not work. What is the exact input you are providing? What do you expect to happen with that input? Do you know the difference between `"%99[^\n]%c"` and `" %99[^\n]%c"` with a leading space? Consider a [mcve].

Comment: The `scanf("%99[^\n]%c", cString)` is missing an argument. And if it is supposed to fix trailing whitespace, it is better to fix leading whitespace with `scanf(" %99[^\n]", cString)`. There may be a problem with `char* str[99]` too which is an array of string pointers.

Comment: If it's supposed to be a string with 99 characters, that should be `char str[99]`. But remember that you have to leave room for the null terminator, so use `%98` in the `scanf()` format string.

Comment: If the problem is to clear the input when too much data was entered (or when enough was) then a subsequent `scanf("%*[^\n]");` should do it.

Comment: If you're treating an array of characters as a null-terminated string, then "clearing" the buffer should just mean assigning the null terminator to the beginning of the array, no?

Comment: Instead of `scanf`, how about `if (fgets(str, 99, stdin) != NULL) { str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;`